# getting a message to be displayed on javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

firstly i will show some code.
html:

```
<label>Password </label> <input type="password" id="pword"><br>
<label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" id="confpword" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;">
<span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br>
```

js:

```
function passwordValidation(){

    var username = document.getElementById("uname");
    var password1 = document.getElementById("pword");
    var confpword1 = document.getElementById("confpword");
    var themsg = document.getElementById("themessage");
    var gc = "#ff6666";

    if (password1.value == confpword1.value){
        themsg.style.color = gc;
        themsg.innerHTML = "Passwords match";
    }else{
        themsg.style.color = gc;
        themsg.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";

    }

    }
```

i cant work out why nothing will show up after i start typing stuff into the input boxes. after i have 'keyed up' once typing into the confirm password box surely 1 of the 2 messages should display. 
i cant work out why the text is not visible.

js fiddle to show problem with current code.
people can edit that if it helps

thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/z5xj4hrt/

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, your JSFiddle setup is just wrong.

You need to put the JavaScript code execution option as "No wrap - In head" or "No wrap - In body" if you want to call functions like that one.

OnDomReady will not keep the function.

See the [corrected JSFiddle](https://goo.gl/wGhyDA)

Comment: ah now i notice it but how do you this in a text editor?

Comment: @ObeseOctopus If the problem occurs in your code on your server it might be an issue with where the function is. Is the JavaScript within a standalone JS file, or is it directly within the HTML file? If so, where is it? Within the `head` or `body` elements?

Comment: ive tried it both wrapped in style tags in both the head and the body function. the function has worked up to the point of displaying the message

Comment: They need to be in `<script></script>` tags, not `style` tags. See [this image](http://i.imgur.com/5g8cTQG.png) for reference.

Comment: sorry that's what i meant, ie the issue still remains

Comment: Look at the image I added in my last comment (or [here](http://i.imgur.com/5g8cTQG.png)).

If you did that and the issue still remains, open your console while writing the passwords and look for JavaScript errors.

Comment: unfortunately that link is blocked due to my companies OTT restriction policy. no errors in the console show when typing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ufmzxqa/ here is an exact jsfiddle for my code. it only works in jsfiddle when i put 'no wrap-in head' like you said to above. how can i apply this same logic to a text editor notepad++ in this case

Comment: what's even more interesting is that when i do ctrl+a (or select all) it actually leaves a space where the writing should be. see this image (http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=bbab130)

Comment: Try adding this right after your `<script src="index1.js></script>` tags: `<script>function passwordValidation() {
    'use strict';
    var username = document.getElementById("uname");
    var password1 = document.getElementById("pword");
    var confpword1 = document.getElementById("confpword");
    var themsg = document.getElementById("themessage");
    var gc = "#ff6666";
 
 if (password1.value == confpword1.value){
  themsg.style.color = gc;
  themsg.innerHTML = "Passwords match";
 }else{
  themsg.style.color = gc;
  themsg.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";
  
}
 
}</script>`